# Securing Module Discovery in Prism/WPF

Tags: wpf, prism

I am using Prism 4 to build a WPF Desktop application. I would like to use the DirectoryModuleCatalog to do module discovery to load modules into the shell. Is there a way to do this securely in order to avoid an outside module being dropped into the ModulePath and loaded up?

Comment: Keep in mind that, if you install to Program Files, then only an admin could drop DLLs into your directory. If you're worried about machine admins messing with your code, then you don't want to write a desktop app.

Comment: That's a good point, Joe, but let's suppose for sake of argument that I DO want to do a desktop app and DON'T want the admins to even inadvertently drop a module in.

I was hoping that signing the Shell project would require signing the modules as well for them to be loaded, but that doesn't seem to be the case without doing some customization of the Catalog or Module Manager.